# Implement adding content only by some pople. Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, web, admin

I am working on dictionary-like web page and I want to implement adding/changing phrases only by few people (my client - which is some small organisation wants to be able to do this by himself). The page does not have any login/registration mechanism etc. (for regular users at least) so I do not want It to have any login button. I wondered if making admin model ( few admins made in seeds for example) and adding login button that is invisible - I thought of using CSS opacity for this one. Is this a good solution ? Is there any other good practice in these sitations? Please dont be afraid to post suggestions. Additionally this is a serious page (my first job as freelancer), so I wonder if my solution is... acceptable? Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quite a standard thing in the web. Most of the websites consists of two parts, customer facing part (sometimes called frontend) and admin panel (called backend). In your case you don't need any login to access frontend part, but you need one for backend part.

Creating hidden button is not needed at all. There simply should be no button at all. If you want to log in as an admin, you simply navigate to `http://my-website-url.com/admin`.

I wouldn't bother with roles et unless your client specified clearly that he needs them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is simple I would still suggest adding a role to a user model. After all he may want to have some user functionality later on. The simplest way to do this would be to use devise and add a role enum column.

Check out the article below and look under the "Enum" section.
http://railsapps.github.io/rails-authorization.html